# Stored Procedure between two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

Let's say I have two tables, table-a and table-b.

Table-a has the following columns: product_id, mission_id, mission_status, mission_source, mission_destinition.

Table-b has two columns: product_id, location_id.

If I were to write a stored procedure which removes a row from table-a where mission_status=1, and then automatically create a new row in table-b consisting of the product_id and mission_destination from the row just removed in table-a, how would I write the stored procedure?

Comment: Also, this sounds like more of a job for a `TRIGGER`, rather than a `STORED PROCEDURE`.

Comment: I suggest switching the order of the steps.  Also, table b does not have a mission destination field.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to accomplish this.  As someone said above, a trigger may be the way to go.  Here's a simple script that might work in this case.

```
--Create test tables
CREATE TABLE #TEMP1
(
product_id int,
mission_Id int,
mission_status int,
mission_source int,
mission_destination VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE #TEMP2
(
product_id int,
location_id VARCHAR(50)
);

--Test data
INSERT INTO #TEMP1 
VALUES(1,1,1,2,'Mars')
INSERT INTO #TEMP1 
VALUES(2,1,1,2,'Jupiter')
INSERT INTO #TEMP1 
VALUES(3,1,1,2,'Venus')
INSERT INTO #TEMP1 
VALUES(4,1,1,2,'Saturn')

--Check for mission_status of 1
SELECT product_id, mission_destination FROM #TEMP1 WHERE mission_status = 1
IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0

BEGIN
INSERT INTO #TEMP2 (product_id,location_id) SELECT product_id, mission_destination FROM #TEMP1 WHERE mission_status = 1 
DELETE FROM #TEMP1 WHERE mission_status = 1
END

SELECT * FROM #TEMP1
SELECT * FROM #TEMP2
```